# powershell The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and created some breakpoints to figure out why the script times out. But I'm getting below error. Any help would be appreciated.

> Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): **"The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send."** At C:\Users\ksingh\Documents\SQL
>   scripts\pdfimportPowerShell.ps1:155 char:5
>   +     $requestStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Here is part of the script and the error occurs at ---

```
bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($data)
```

## function to call token service

```
function GetNewToken()
{
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($temptokenserviceurl)

    $request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = $false

    $request.ContentType = "application/json"

    $request.Method = "POST"

    $data = (New-Object PSObject |
        Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty username $temptokenserviceuser |    
        Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty password $temptokenservicepassword
    ) | ConvertTo-JSON

    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($data)

    $request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length

    $requestStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()

    $requestStream.write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)

    $response = $request.GetResponse()

    $StreamReader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($response.getResponseStream())

    $Json = $StreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    $responseString = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json

    $response.Close()

    return $responseString.tokenId
}
```